# React Native Sqlite Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Has anyone ever encountered this error? Or could anyone point me into the right direction to fixing this one on the screenshot below.

[SQLITE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4xap.png)

Comment: Hope you would have resolved the issue. If not can you please share the SQLite plugin name which you have used in our React Native application, based on that we can help you.

Comment: Hi Pardeep I've already fixed the issue, and it is exactly not because of the SQLite, but because of invoking my app when it is killed. I just made my app call the service first before going back to the database.